# Full matrix ring over an infinite division ring with a finite maximal unital subring?

Tags: matrices, division-rings

I'm wondering if there is an infinite division ring $D$ and a finite unital subring $R$ of the full matrix ring $M_n(D)$ ($n$ some positive integer) such that there are no rings properly between $R$ and $M_n(D)$. Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Could you say why this sort of question arises, and maybe either why you expect there is, or else that there isn't, such a datum?

Comment: I see that a ring with a finite maximal subring must be finite, and so this answers the question.

Comment: @Greg If you know longer need an answer, can you either delete your question, or answer yourself and accept your answer?  This way it won't clog up the "unanswered" queue.

Comment: Oops - thanks for this and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

If a ring has a finite maximal subring, the ring itself is finite. This appears to be due to Laffey from 1992.

Comment: Could you give a precise reference?